# Add view to top all activity by windowmanager

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I want to add view to show all activity.

1. When add view and I close actvity then view still display
2. When I close app , view is removed.

Thankyou and Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a `Service` and getWindowManager in your Service.
2. create a `WindowManager.LayoutParams` instance and set type to `LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE`, then call `windowManager.addView(view, lp)`.
3. send a intent to your service when close app, call `windowManager.removeView(view)` in Service.

When are you using Android 6.0+ you need ask for permision
`

```
public static int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_CODE = 2525;  

public void addOverlay() {     
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {         
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);     
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for answer, I will try it .

Comment: I use LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE , and can not click other current actvity or back button. PS. I  add flag  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH

Comment: `WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);`

Comment: Thankyou , but I use android mashmallow , I startservice and can not show view anymore.